# What is the parent of a set of Synonyms referred to as?

Tags: synonyms

The synonyms for "love" include: "affection", "passion", "yearning" and so on. In relation to its synonyms what would the word "love" be referred to as?

Example Sentence:

*The synonyms of "love" are affection, passion and yearning.*

Now the incomplete sentence:

*The word "Love" is the **[insert word here]** of affection, passion and yearning.*

I am trying to think of a word that would help me establish a reverse relation. However all I could come up with are words and phrases like "Source", "Target of synonyms" and so on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misconception. No single member of a set of synonyms is regarded as prototypical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Isn't it worth correcting the misconception (especially in case others have it)?

Comment: @ SteveES Certainly. That's what 'comments' are for. / The overlap of synonyms, and commutivity, has already been discussed in previous threads. Repeating material every time a similar question is submitted isn't good housekeeping.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hadn't realised that it had been discussed before. Do you have links? And surely that would make it a duplicate?

Comment: @SteveES See [Do synonyms {always mean} exactly ... the same {as each other}?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128380/do-synonyms-exactly-stand-for-the-same) for an overview of synonymity, [Are synonyms always bidirectional?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88199/are-synonyms-always-bidirectional/88206#88206) for the commutivity  of the 'is a synonym of' relationship W1~W2 // and see [this discussion of the extent of overlap of senses in a particular case](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188407/worried-person-vs-concerned-person/188409#188409).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As far as I'm aware, there is no such word**. The existence of such a word would rely upon a one-way, or hierarchical relationship between synonyms, which is not the case; **synonyms are reversible**.

I.e.:
If word B is a synonym of word A, then word A is also a synonym of word B (although sometimes in fewer contexts). (For most words at least) word A was not "the original meaning" from which word B arose. It therefore doesn't make sense to suggest the existence of a parent-child relationship between synonyms.

You should probably change your sentence to:

> The word "Love" has the synonyms affection, passion and yearning.

or

> Affection, passion and yearning are all synonyms for love.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Much appreciated! This definitely clarifies a lot for me.

Comment: If A and B are synonyms, there are contexts where A and B may be interchanged with no or negligible change in meaning. Definition. It may well be possible to use A in more contexts overall than B, but saying 'B is also a synonym of A, but to a lesser degree' is incorrect. / It _is_ a duplicate (if one can decide on a valid question hidden behind the misconception).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That was what I was trying to get at by saying "to a lesser degree", I guess I perhaps mean "in fewer contexts". E.g. if one word encompasses more meaning/has a more generic definition, like table and furniture, or ants and insects.

Answer (score 2):

In *some* paper thesauri, a list of synonyms starts with a **headword**.  This is mainly an organisational feature rather than a linguistic one, but tends to be a fairly common word that's also a good synonym for the rest of the list.  For example, Roget's (arbitrary edition found online)

> **492. Scholar. --- N** Scholar, connoisseur, *savant*, pundit...

Unfortunately this is a better fit to the question title than the example, but may explain what you're thinking of.

Comment: Thank you for shedding light on headwords. That is something new to me.